# Find object in array with a matching key using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects, each object has a unique key.
Example:

```
const myArray = [
{uKey1: 'hey', otherValue: 1},
{uKey2: 'hey', otherValue: 1},
{uKey3: 'hey', otherValue: 1}
];
```

I want to use lodash to do something like

```
lodash(myArray, 'uKey2')
```

And have it return the object with uKey2

Comment: Not lodash but you can take a look at `Array.prototype.find()` maybe: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Not entirely related, but I don't understand what the use case is for lodash. Can someone explain it to me? Is it for compatibility with old browsers or something?

Comment: @Klaycon somewhat.  Many functions that lodash served have been pulled into the language proper.  However, there are still a few functions that have not.

Comment: @zero298 That makes sense, but my kneejerk reaction with many questions like these is "you don't need lodash, javascript array helpers already do it" - and I imagine that isn't a sufficient answer for one reason or another.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the key name to _.find on the second argument:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const myArray = [{
      uKey1: 'hey',
      otherValue: 1
    },
    {
      uKey2: 'hey',
      otherValue: 1
    },
    {
      uKey3: 'hey',
      otherValue: 1
    }
  ];

  console.log(_.find(myArray, 'uKey1'))
  console.log(_.find(myArray, 'uKey2'))
  console.log(_.find(myArray, 'uKey3'))
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just combine `_.find` with `_.has`.

You can even create a mixin (aka plugin) as seen below.

The pure JS version is not that bad.

```js
_.mixin({
  findObjectByPresentKey : function(arr, key) {
    return _.find(arr, function(obj) {
      return _.has(obj, key);
    })
  }
});

const myArray = [
  { uKey1: 'hey', otherValue: 1 },
  { uKey2: 'hey', otherValue: 1 },
  { uKey3: 'hey', otherValue: 1 }
]

// In-line
console.log(_.find(myArray, 'uKey3'))

// As a plugin
console.log(_.findObjectByPresentKey(myArray, 'uKey3'))

// Pure JS (Edge)
console.log(myArray.find(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('uKey3')));

// IE 9+
console.log(myArray.filter(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('uKey3')).pop());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Please refer to: [`_.find(collection, [predicate=_.identity], [fromIndex=0])`](https://lodash.com/docs/#find)

> ```js
> // The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
> _.find(users, 'active');
> // => object for 'barney'
> ```